# How to insert file into FormData Object Array on Postman?

Tags: postman, multipartform-data, form-data

I need to upload files with users documents information just like so:

{
"documents": [
"documentType": "string",
"file": "byte[]",
],
"requestId": "string",
}

how do i do this on Postman?

i've tried many ways, such as:

[image: Postman]

also changing to just "file" + file, and "documents[0]" + file, and "documents[0][file]".

Answer (score 1):

Use `documents.file` instead of `documents[file]` to access the content. For example:

[Postman Key-Values Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3NW1.png)